# How to bulk edit the fields of a group of files in a Sharepoint 2010 library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store

I tried to use the Data View but it says my field is Read Only.  The field in question is a term store field. How can I edit these files without doing so one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

it's impossible from out-of-the-box, but you can use 3-rd party solutions.
For example from VirtoSoftware ([link](http://www.virtosoftware.com/products/bulk/virto-bulk-data-edit)) , BambooSolutions, or SharePoint Boost.

Also you can upload multiple files with predefined properties (managed metadata supported) with [Bulk File Upload](http://www.virtosoftware.com/products/bulk/virto-bulk-file-upload).

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit managed metadata columns in the datasheet view, but you can in SharePoint 2013.

For 2010, you can use [SharePoint 2010 Batch Edit](http://sp2010batchedit.codeplex.com/) for bulk updating managed metadata using the SharePoint ribbon.